# Lagging over multiple time periods in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I'm trying to lag some variables in a DataFrame (and am expressly avoiding using time series), and am getting a funny result. To be precise, I'm trying to assemble a number of lags into a single object, i.e. a 1- and 2-period lag of the column called "orders."  Here's what I'm doing:

```
time=18:29
orders=c(76,77,78,79,72,81,79,85,93,81,72,60)

 data=data.frame(time=time,orders=orders)

 lagage<-lag(data$orders, k=-1:-2)

Error in `tsp<-`(`*tmp*`, value = p - (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0)) : 
invalid time series parameters specified
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (k != round(k)) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0) :
 longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I'm pretty confused by why I'm getting this error as I've used the lag() function many times before with no issues.  Maybe it's a brain fart on my side, but I wanted to check with you guys to see what's going on.

**EDIT**

Should have been more clear here-- I'm looking to fill the indexes that are affected with lags by NAs.  The lagging I showed above works of I coerce the dataframe to a zoo object, like so:

```
data<-as.zoo(data)
lagage<-lag(data$orders, k=-1:-3)


  lag-1 lag-2 lag-3
2     76    NA    NA
3     77    76    NA
4     78    77    76
5     79    78    77
6     72    79    78
7     81    72    79
8     79    81    72
9     85    79    81
10    93    85    79
11    81    93    85
12    72    81    93
```

Of course, I can re-coerce the new data back to a data frame, but want to avoid these steps.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `lag`'s `k` argument only accepts a single integer.

Comment: You should be aware that `lag` is going to return a time series object, so if you are expressly trying to avoid it (unsure why?) that might not be the best option.  Also, are you sure you want `k` to be negative?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: I'm sure they want `k` to be negative. `lag` uses the unconventional convention that positive values for `k` mean lag the value _forward_ in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the previous answer, try this:

```
foo <- function(k) c(rep(NA, abs(k)), lag(data$orders, k=k)[abs(k):length(data$orders)])
sapply(-1:-2, foo)
```

`lag` for a vector will return a vector of the same length, and when you combine them in a data frame or matrix you'll just get identical series. It doesn't pad with NA's and drop elements at the end, which is what you want when lagging in a data frame or matrix.

Comment: Thanks.  Just what I 'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following instead:

```
 sapply(-1:-2, function(k) lag(data$orders, k=k))
```

you might want to use `, simplify=FALSE` if you'd like to preserve the attributes

Comment: I tried your code, but the sapply function doesn't spit out a lagged matrix -- it just repeats the existing `data$orders` column.

Comment: @user1884063, hence my comment about setting simplify to false and keeping the attributes.  It's not altogether clear what you expect the output to be.  If you could edit your question to include an example, that would be helpful